# Sales : Orders :How to add custom order status programmatically

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order, magento2.2, order-status

I need to add **custom status** for an order programatically
I have below controller file to save order status.
I need to add custom status as cancel initiated.Provide me a solution...

**Controller file**

```
public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = 3;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('');
        $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);// Here I need to add custom status as Cancel initiated
        $order->save();

        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

**It is failed to fetch or change the status dropdown**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create new status **Stores > Order Status** and set the code for status `custom_cancel` and use below code

```
        $orderId = 3;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
        $state = $order->getState();
        $status = 'custom_cancel';
        $comment = '';
        $isNotified = false;
        $order->setState($state);
        $order->setStatus($status);
        $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $comment);
        $order->save();
```

Comment: It added the status in DB but failed to fetch in Sales->order page for id 3

Comment: @Jayashree add it from admin panel just as i mention and check it is listed in `Stores > Order Status`

Comment: I need to add status via programatically not in admin... If I said wrong Please correct me

Comment: @Jayashree i know what you want but you have to follow the rule here first add the status in statuses in admin panel then run the code with status code. Then it will be shown in order view if you add directly then in order view it show blank order status.create the status then use it.

Comment: see the updated post , It works fine But failed to fetch in status Dropdown

Comment: @Jayashree here is logic work with order history status dropdown the order status state must be same. you have to assign state `processing` to status `custom_cancel`  in `Stores > Order Status` in `Assign state to status`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69325/discussion-between-jayashree-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: state is not assigned

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you must create a custom status and assigned a state like processing. in an upgradeData or InstallData

```
      $statusData = array('status'=> 'custom', 'state'=> 'processing', 'label' => 'custom state');
      try {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $statusFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\StatusFactory')->load($orderId);

            $status = $statusFactory->create(['data' => $statusData]);
            // Firstly, create the status
            $status->save();
            // Secondly, assign the status to state
            $status->assignState($statusData['state']);
        } catch (CouldNotSaveException $exception) {
            $this->logger->critical($exception);
        }
```

Comment: You are welcom, my response helped you or not?

Comment: Yes. It will work

Comment: I am getting the following error: Source class "\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\Status" for "Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\StatusFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: You must remove all file in var/generation

Answer (score 0):

i created:

```
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_number);
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
```

If i check the status programmaticaly with

```
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_number);
return $order->getState();
```

the status is canceled but if i see to frontend it not changed.

Why?