# add new order status in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

I added new order status by **System -> Order Statuses**

My doubt is need to add that status name in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` this file.?

Currently that file has this code

```
    const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
    const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
    const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
    const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
    const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
    const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
    const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
```

Need to add my status name here.?

If yes,how to do that without write core file.?

Anyone can tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are states not the status. If you want to assign any state to your status you can do that from `System -> Order Statuses`. No need to change in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`. for more information [read](https://www.queryoverflow.gdn/query/orders-belongs-to-custom-created-order-status-is-not-showing-in-my-account-recent-orders-10_153326.html)

Comment: If I write my status in that file. I can use like this $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_DELIVERED, true) . Is it correct?

Comment: @NagarajJuro STATE is something else. if you want to add status just follow my solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203288/sales-orders-how-to-add-custom-order-status-programmatically/203291#203291

Comment: Now i understood. Thank you @Qaisar Satti.