# Magento 2 cannot change order status to custom from complete

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

I want to change the order status from complete to custom  status but unable to do so. My code is:

```
 $orderState = 'customstatus';
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus('customstatus');
        $order->save();
```

Still it remains same.
How to change?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203288/sales-orders-how-to-add-custom-order-status-programmatically

Comment: I have followed the procedure given over there and order status is showing in the list but I am unable to change from 'Complete' in front end.